# sql - Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

this query works fine

```
select *  from
(select meas.Inspection_No, case 
when ISNUMERIC(meas.InspectionValue) = 1 then
    cast(meas.InspectionValue as decimal(10,2))
    else 0 End as IVEKVol, meas.InspectionValue,  spec.Name, spec.   [Description], meas.LastDate, meas.ID  from
(select ism.InspectionSpecificationMeasurementID, ism.Name, ism. [Description]  from PT_InspectionSpecification [is]
inner join PT_InspectionSpecification_Measurement ism on   [is].InspectionSpecification_No = ism.InspectionSpecification_No
where [is].PartDescription = 'Anode Dispense' and   [is].InspectionSpecification_type = 'Control Plan' and ism.Name LIKE 'I-IVEKVol    Recorded%') spec
inner join 
PT_InspectionItem_Measurement  meas on  spec.InspectionSpecificationMeasurementID =   meas.InspectionSpecificationMeasurementID) data
```

but when i add the where clause "where data.IVEKVol > 0" i get the error "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric"

```
select *  from
(select meas.Inspection_No, case 
when ISNUMERIC(meas.InspectionValue) = 1 then
    cast(meas.InspectionValue as decimal(10,2))
    else 0 End as IVEKVol, meas.InspectionValue,  spec.Name, spec.   [Description], meas.LastDate, meas.ID  from
(select ism.InspectionSpecificationMeasurementID, ism.Name, ism. [Description]  from PT_InspectionSpecification [is]
inner join PT_InspectionSpecification_Measurement ism on   [is].InspectionSpecification_No = ism.InspectionSpecification_No
where [is].PartDescription = 'Anode Dispense' and   [is].InspectionSpecification_type = 'Control Plan' and ism.Name LIKE 'I-IVEKVol    Recorded%') spec
inner join 
PT_InspectionItem_Measurement  meas on  spec.InspectionSpecificationMeasurementID =   meas.InspectionSpecificationMeasurementID) data
where data.IVEKVol > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `data.IVEKVol` column is `NVARCHAR` type, `0` is `numberic` type

To compare two columns, DBMS must convert two columns type to a same type.

If `data.IVEKVol` column have data like: '1', '22',... '' you can try:

```
WHERE CAST(data.IVEKVol AS INT) > 0  -- Can FOAT, DOUBLE, NUMBERIC, ... instead
```

If not, I think your code like:

```
WHERE data.IVEKVol  > N'0' -- recommend
-- OR
WHERE data.IVEKVol  > '0'  -- not recommend
```

Comment: data.IVEKVol is not NVARCHAR, it was cast to a decimal:       when ISNUMERIC(meas.InspectionValue) = 1 then cast(meas.InspectionValue as decimal(10,2)) else 0 End as IVEKVol